# java - How to convert Float to BigDecimal?

Tags: java

I would like to know how to convert `java.lang.Float` to `java.Math.BigDecimal`. Can this be achieved?

Comment: If you need BigDecimal accuracy, don't use `float` in the first place, use `double` at least or parse the original number as `String`

Answer (score 3):

Yes try this,

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(123.4f));
```